# How to add a new button next to the page action buttons on the admin product edit page of Magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to add a new button next to the page action buttons (Back, Save) on the admin product edit page of Magento 2. This new button will perform a custom action.  Can anyone please let me know, how can I create new button in the page-actions buttons area of the admin product edit page. I am using Magento 2.0.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I have found out that, we can create a custom button in the admin product edit page by editing the _prepareLayout() function inside the core file, vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit.php

In order to do this, I have extended this block file in my module. For that, first I have edited the di.xml file in my module (MyVendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml)

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" />
```

Then I have extended the Block file to my module (MyVendor/MyModule/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php)

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Product;

class Edit extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit 
{

```
/**
 * Add elements in layout
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->getToolbar()->addChild(
                'custom_buttonfor_myaction',
                'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button',
                [
                    'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                    'title' => __('Custom Button'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl(
                        'mycustompath/*/',
                        ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0)]
                    ) . '\')',
                    'class' => 'action-default primary'
                ]
            );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

}

This Creates the custom button in the Admin product edit page.